# Corda Network-Map is up and running, but Notary is not in whitelist

Tags: corda, notary

I have a Corda Infrastructure with some nodes and a (not validating) notary. They're all using a Network Map for the compatibility zone, and all the corda nodes, including the notary, download the same network-parameters file.

When executing a flow, Corda gives me an Exception because the Notary is not on the network parameters whitelist. I cannot find anything anything about that on R3 Documentation.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Notary [O=Notary, L=Cosenza, C=IT (owningKey = DLAdtNkbnrjn6FGwzE4sCaiDS3tRgMw3KhZfA7bD3icYK1)] specified by the transaction is not on the network parameter whitelist:  []
    at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt.checkNotaryWhitelisted(TransactionUtils.kt:257) ~[corda-core-4.8.jar:?]
```

Note that I'm using a fixed Notary X500 Name in the Flow code instead of "preferredNotary" because it won't be found. I think it is because of the same problem.

Do I have to do something explicit to add Notary in network parameters whitelist?

Comment: Hi are you using the network bootstrapper for deploying the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to do something explicit to add Notary in network parameters whitelist?

Yeah you do. Since you are using a network-map-service your node will get its network-parameters from there.

What you'll have to do then is

1. delete your current network-parameters for every Node.
2. whitelist your Notary Node into your network-map-service
3. restart all your Nodes so they can retrieve the new network-parameters from the network-map-service where the new Notary is assigned as such

I don't know which network-map-service exactly you use but i assume its nms by cordite. You can read up on how to whitelist a Notary here: https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/-/blob/master/FAQ.md#14-start-the-notary-node